# Can you class your td tags

Tags: html-table

I'm making a site for school and I wanted to know if you could class td tags.  So you could have one or a few cells with colors.

Comment: It would've taken less time to try it and find out than to post the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of coloring table cells: https://plnkr.co/edit/LJL2inL0p9qMzS0dStiI?p=preview

html

```
<tr>
  <td align="center" class="red">red</td>
  <td align="center" class="green">green</td>
  <td align="center" class="blue">blue</td>
</tr>
```